# How to make CppUnit logging more verbose?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

I'm using CppUnit to write unit tests for a C++ library. By default it prints a single "." character to the console for each test. I'd like to log the name of each test on a separate line, before the test runs.

I've looked into the CppUnit API, but it's not at all obvious how to customize the output. Instead of offering customization options, it's more of a framework that you can plug new handlers into. (The tutorial hasn't helped, either.) I could probably spend a day figuring out how to do this, but I can't afford to lose the time. Could someone provide a quick snippet that can customize the per-test log output?

Comment: What kind of logging do you need? And how do you use cppunit? There are several ways depending on how you use cppunit.

Comment: As I said above, "I'd like to log the name of each test on a separate line, before the test runs."

Comment: I've actually dumped CppUnit. I discovered Catch, which is a million times nicer, and am converting all of my tests to it. https://github.com/philsquared/Catch

Answer (score 0):

It is simple enough to define and install a custom progress listener to emit the name of each test before it's performed.  Here's one I wrote today:

```
class MyCustomProgressTestListener : public CppUnit::TextTestProgressListener {
 public:
     virtual void startTest(CppUnit::Test *test) {
         fprintf(stderr, "starting test %s\n", test->getName().c_str());
     }
};
```

Install it on a test runner like this:

```
CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;
MyCustomProgressTestListener progress;
runner.eventManager().addListener(&progress);
```